# Why appears error Run/time error: shape(unknown member): Object does not exist after executing AddMediaObjectFromEmbedTag

Tags: powerpoint

I need to embed video file from You Tube to slide in vba code. I use method:

Set PPTShp = PPTSld.Shapes.AddMediaObjectFromEmbedTag("https://youtu.be/fiz94XbgrJ0", Top:=0, Left:=0, Height:=171, Width:=312)

Video file is visile on the slide, but on the next line, when I want to grab the media format object:

Set PPTMediaFormat = PPTShp.MediaFormat

appeared error message: Shhaoe (unknown member): Object does not exist

I tried the method: Shapes.AddMediaObject2 method, but the same error appeared again on the line:
Set PPTMediaFormat = PPTShp.MediaFormat.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved.
I changed .... Dim PPTMediaFormat As MediaFormat  ... to ...   Dim PPTLinkFormat As LinkFormat

and

Set PPTMediaFormat = PPTShp.MediaFormat  ... to ...       Set PPTLinkFormat = PPTShp.LinkFormat

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).